# PHP - Select part of a string between two characters

Tags: php, regex, string

I've been doing research into this and I believe the answer is do to with regular expressions but I just can't get my head around them.

I have a number of strings and I need to select a number between two characters. Here is an example string

```
&user18339=18339,20070103,175439,pmt,793,A/3/1/2,335,793,A/3/1/2,
```

I need the number that occurs after `A/3/1/2,` and before the following `,`

In this example I need to select `335`. I can do this using explode however I run into problems when I need to get more than one number from a string, like in the example below.

Here is another example string

```
&user31097=31097,20070105,092612,pmt,4190,A/3/1/2,142,1162,A/3/1/1,22,2874,A/3/1/2,1046,4622,A/3/1/2,25,2872,A/3/1/2,
```

Again I need to get the numbers after the `A/3/1/2,` and before the following `,`. So in this example I would want to take `142`, `1046` and `25`.

If anyone could let me know how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have several occurrences of "A/3/1/2" in your examples, and did not specify what to do with that.

Comment: Is it always the "integer" that follows an "A/#/#/#" sequence after the "pmt" string? (e.g. there could be 1, 2, n occurrences?)

Comment: Can you please give some semantic meaning to these values?

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = '&user31097=31097,20070105,092612,pmt,4190,A/3/1/2,142,1162,A/3/1/1,22,2874,A/3/1/2,1046,4622,A/3/1/2,25,2872,A/3/1/2,';
preg_match_all('/A\/3\/1\/2,([0-9]*?),/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: @JWH89, If this answer works for you, you should check-mark it as answered.  Also, please up-vote any answers that were helpful to you.     If an answer was *not* helpful, comments -- as to why it didn't work for you -- help everyone figure out the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/A\/3\/1\/2,([^,]+),/', $input, $matches = array());
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: [^,] will match anything until "," witch will match a string too , hes asking how to retrive the number not everithing .

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match_all('#A/3/1/2,([^,]*),#',$str,$matches)) {                        
        // $matches[1] will have the required results.
}
```

[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/9i92V)

Comment: [^,] will match anything until "," witch will match a string too , hes asking how to retrive the number not everithing .